# Entity inside a Webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a Webform that has an option for a number of tickets. Depending on the number of tickets I need to take information for each ticket, which I was thinking would be the entity?

So if they pick 2 tickets I will need to show the fields some how for the information to then be taken twice.

Any help?

Comment: Are you definitely tied to webform for this? It would probably be a bit easier to get a stable solution with the entity form module instead. Then you can easily use other modules like field collection or inline entity form on top of it.

Comment: Yes not tied to the webform module. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Would it be difficult to get any number of these field groups to appear depending upon the ticket number field? Or maybe I just have a button called add registration which adds them one at a time..

Comment: IF you had an unlimited value field collection or inline entity form entity reference, it would provide an 'Add another' button. I'm sure you could make it say 'Add another ticket' or similar.

Comment: Yes using hook_form_alter, thanks I did actually just realise that! haah thanks nonetheless

Comment: Cool, I've added a proper answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webform module doesn't really provide such a feature without either using unstable dev version modules (and maybe achieving it) or custom code.

An easier alternative would be to use the [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module, which allows you to use any add-on modules that work with Drupal's field API.

This means you could achieve your requirement using something like the [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) or [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) modules to provide a repeatable group of fields. In that case you can set the field to unlimited values and it will give the user the option to 'Add another item'.

With the Inline Entity Form option, you would have a separate entity for your ticket and you form will have an [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field using the inline entity form widget, which will provide the full form, inline, whenever the user clicks the 'Add another' button.

Answer (score 1):

Since I see that you are not tied to the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) Module, why not just make a separate Custom Type and make the Node Creation/Edit form for that type the Form?

You can use the [Simplify](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify) module to hide the extra administrative stuff so that it is more presentable.

When using a standard custom Content Type, you have access to the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field which would solve the limitations of [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform).